# Is it possible to return similar locations via Foursquare API?

Tags: foursquare

Given a location e.g. Santa Monica, Los Angeles - is it possible to use Foursquare API to return other similar locations?

Example, the below may be used as item comparison data:

- high number of restaurants
- cafes
- park
- beach

Through the comparison of venues and user check-ins, I would be interested in discovering other similar locations within X miles. A result set similar to Santa Monica could be Manhattan Beach, Huntington Beach.

Answer (score 0):

We have a [venues/similar](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/similar) endpoint, but that's more suited for telling you which venues (restaurants, bars, museums, etc.) are similar to each other, not entire cities based on metrics you're interested in.